How to select categorical features and numerical features for running train test?
I was trying to concatenate two lists of features with different lengths which was causing a ValueError because the shapes of the two lists cannot be broadcast together. I was trying to select categorical and numerical features from the dataframe.
I wrote this:
categorical_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'category']).columns 
df = df.dropna(subset=categorical_features)
numerical_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64']).columns
X = df[categorical_features + numerical_features].copy()
y = df['JobSatisfaction'].copy() 

I got this:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (87,) (42,) 


Pandas does not like concatenating objects with different lengths.
Try using a union instead:
categorical_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'category']).columns
df = df.dropna(subset=categorical_features) 
numerical_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64']).columns

all_features = categorical_features.union(numerical_features) 

X = df[all_features].copy()
y = df['JobSatisfaction'].copy()

You could also use append:
categorical_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'category']).columns
df = df.dropna(subset=categorical_features)  
numerical_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64']).columns

all_features = categorical_features.append(numerical_features)

X = df[all_features].copy() 
y = df['JobSatisfaction'].copy() 

When working with Pandas, you'll almost always use these two rather than concatenating.
